# I need to keep the container centered on the page with css grid

Tags: html, css

I want to keep the container grid 2 centered with the spaces on both sides
on any screen size(responsive), but what happens right now is the side spaces shrink to nothing as the screen size decreases. I'm wondering how I can solve this without breaking all the work done so far.

I made a codepen, I need the container grid2 to be centered with margins on either side no matter the width of the screen.

```
<div class="grid2">
    <div class="Jumbotext-1">Deliver a unique</div>
    <div class="Jumbotext-2">experience</div>
    <div class="blurb-text">
        We can work together today<br>
        to create an exceptional product<br>
        that screams to the world,<br>
        I belong to you.
    </div>
</div>

.grid2 {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
border: 1px solid red;
max-width: 90rem;
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
padding: 72px 0px 100px;

}
```

https://codepen.io/Jenson-co-in/pen/BGzgJr

Answer (score 0):

Use auto width and apply the desired margin **(if you want fixed margins)** to the sides:

```
.grid2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 90rem;
  width: auto;
  margin: auto 10px;
  padding: 72px 0px 100px;
}
```

Or you can use auto margin for the sides and have the width be less than 100% **(if you want fixed responsive width)**:

```
.grid2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 90rem;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 72px 0px 100px;
}
```

Comment: Im not sure if this is compatible with grid, on smaller resolutions the right margin breaks the layout

Comment: I just tested it on codepen and seems to work fine. Provide more examples if you want me to take a look ;)

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your time!

https://codepen.io/Jenson-co-in/pen/BGzgJr

So I updated the codepen with more information about my use case, the line "deliver a unique" has to be in one line, followed by the text "experience" and the blurb next to it. 

The issue is on smaller widths this layout goes to garbage. This is my very specific problem.

Your solution is what I want to happen, but the behavior breaks the layout for some reason..